# Redirect to a different page through registration, depending on page

Tags: php, user-registration, conditional-content

I have the following code in my function.php:

```
add_filter('foo_registration_redirect', 'my_foo_registration_redirect', 12);

function my_foo_registration_redirect( $redirect_to) {
    if (is_page(1693)) {
         $redirect_to = '/my-page';
         return $redirect_to;
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

The if statement is for some reason not true when I'm on the corresponding page. I also tried using

```
 if (is_page('page-name')) { ... }
```

which also never returns true, despite being on the right page. Any help is appreciated. The filter works as it should if I change the code to

```
function my_foo_registration_redirect( $redirect_to) {
         $redirect_to = '/my-page';
         return $redirect_to; 
}
```

However, I need the conditional, as I have 2 registration forms, on each their page, and one of them needs to point somewhere else.

Comment: What is the `foo_registration_redirect` filter? The correct one is `registration_redirect`

Comment: Check and see what the $post object is at that point in time. It's possible that it's not set yet, hence there is no current page for is_page() to return. Do something like global $post; var_export($post); die(); just so it spits out the object on the page so you can see what it is.

Comment: Also never hardcode the urls. Use `get_the_permalink` instead.

Comment: The `foo_registration_redirect` is basically the same as the woocommerce redirect filter. 
@IndustrialThemes - When I do that in my function it returns NULL. But how would I go about checking what page the form is submitted from?

And thanks for the heads up about the hardcoded url.

Comment: Aha, so the $post object is not set yet when that filter runs for some reason. You can see where the form was submitted from using this: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

Comment: Or you can pass a GET/POST variable with the id of the registration page.

Comment: @IndustrialThemes Thanks so much! I changed the function to the following, and it works now:
function wr_wc_registration_redirect( $redirect_to) {
  
  
  `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== get_the_permalink(1693)) {
   return $redirect_to;
  }
  $redirect_to = '/videoguide-startpakke';
  return $redirect_to;
}`
I tried that Laxmana, but I had trouble doing it right sadly (I'm pretty new to this whole programming thing)

Comment: Great solution! That looks like it will work nicely.

Comment: :) it's ok. My only concern about checking headers like `HTTP_REFERER` is that they can be spoofed easily but in your case I don't think that is a problem. With variables like GET/POST you have total control and you are not tied up with hardcore ids

Comment: I just read about referer spoofing since you mentioned it, and you're correct, the only thing a user could gain from it is to be redirected to a different page on the site, which is to their own disadvantage honestly, as all I needed this for was to give a better flow on the site :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the function to the following works, as it checks to see if the form was submitted from the correct page:

```
function my_foo_registration_redirect( $redirect_to) {
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== get_the_permalink(1693)) {
            return $redirect_to;
        }
        $redirect_to = '/videoguide-startpakke';
        return $redirect_to;
}
```

Thanks a lot for the super helpful comments!

#### EDIT: Here's a slightly more polished solution

```
function my_foo_registration_redirect( $redirect_to) {
        $post_id = 1693;
        $post = get_post($post_id); 
        $slug = $post->post_name;

        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== get_the_permalink($post_id)) {
            return $redirect_to;
        }
        $redirect_to = $slug;
        return $redirect_to;
}
```